# How to upload a photo to 500px using the BackgroundUploader in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-async

I've got following code for uploading using OAuth.

```
public async Task UploadPhotoContinueAsync(IEnumerable<StorageFile> files)
{
    var uri = string.Format("https://api.500px.com/v1/photos/upload?name={0}&description={1}&privacy=0&category=0", "test name", "test description");
    var backgroudUploader = new BackgroundUploader();
    var headers = OAuthUtility.BuildBasicParameters(consumerKey, consumerSecret, uri, HttpMethod.Post, GetAccessToken());
    var header = string.Empty;
    var file = files.First();
    foreach (var item in headers)
    {
        header += string.Format(@"{0}=""{1}"",", item.Key, item.Value);
    }

    header = header.Remove(header.Length - 1);

    backgroudUploader.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", string.Format("OAuth {0}", header));
    backgroudUploader.SetRequestHeader("Filename", file.Name);

    var op = backgroudUploader.CreateUpload(new Uri(uri), file);
    try
    {
            var result = await op.StartAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

The problem is that everytime I start the operation I get a Internal Server Error from the API.

I can't seem to figure out what the problem is.

Did anybody figured this out? Thanks.

EDIT:

I finally made Fiddler work. Here are the headers that the app sends to the API:

[image: Commented out sensitive information]

Comment: Any message in the error that you get? Could it cause a problem if the file names "test" already exists on that location?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't see what message is embedded in the response. At least, I don't know how to view it when using an UploadOperation. It's just status code 500 and Internal Server Error. In addition I've uploaded multiple "test" named images using their test console API.

Comment: If you install Fiddler, you should be able to see exactly what is going up and what is coming back.

Comment: The problem is Fiddler is not working. I've tried :(

Comment: Make sure you do the configuration for Fiddler for Win8. Also, you can try manually creating the same request (setting the headers manually in Fiddler) and seeing what the response is. Are you checking the request before making it? Making sure that your OAuth token is getting parsed properly, etc.

Comment: Finally got Fiddler to work. Is this not the correct format? http://i.imgur.com/WCKE6Aw.png

Comment: Click on the "Raw" tab in the response panel. You may get there more information of what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it's not very professional, but I finally found a way to fix my code :)

Here's the updated function that works:

```
public async Task UploadPhotoContinueAsync(IEnumerable<StorageFile> files)
{
    var uri = string.Format("https://api.500px.com/v1/photos/upload?name={0}&description={1}&privacy=0&category=0", "test name", "test description");
    var backgroudUploader = new BackgroundUploader();
    var headers = OAuthUtility.BuildBasicParameters(consumerKey, consumerSecret, uri, HttpMethod.Post, GetAccessToken());
    var header = string.Empty;
    var file = files.First();
    foreach (var item in headers)
    {
        header += string.Format(@"{0}=""{1}"", ", item.Key, item.Value);
    }

    header = header.Remove(header.Length - 2);

    backgroudUploader.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", string.Format("OAuth {0}", header));
    backgroudUploader.SetRequestHeader("Filename", file.Name);
    string boundary = "----------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
    backgroudUploader.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
    backgroudUploader.Method = "POST";

    var parts = new List<BackgroundTransferContentPart>();
    var part = new BackgroundTransferContentPart();
    part.SetHeader("Content-Disposition", @"form-data; name=""file""; filename=""" + file.Name + "\"");
    part.SetFile(file);
    parts.Add(part);

    var op = await backgroudUploader.CreateUploadAsync(new Uri(uri), parts, "", boundary);
    try
    {
        var result = await op.StartAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Thanks everyone that helped!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that there's no content type in the Fiddler version. Looks like 500px requires a multi-part content type, and your console screen shot from twitter shows that being set.

Have you tried using BackgroundUploader.SetRequestHeader to force the content type?

backgroundUploader.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundray);
backgroundUploader.Method = "POST";

If that fails, maybe use BackgroundTransferContentPart?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.backgroundtransfercontentpart.aspx

Some ideas here:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/9b2a31c0-30e3-499b-a265-10e8d97a79ad/upload-video-file-to-server-with-backgrounduploader?forum=winappswithcsharp

Comment: Except that you did that and then posted it as the answer. :) Glad you got it working.